extracting blocks of data using numpy
Here is a problem I am having:
I want to plot some energy bands obtained with Quantum Espresso. The data comes in a file with two columns. The columns are separated by empty lines into blocks. Each block corresponds to a band.
Here is an example of the first two blocks:
    0.0000  -44.2709
    0.0250  -44.2709
    0.0500  -44.2709
    0.0750  -44.2708
    0.1000  -44.2708
    0.1250  -44.2707
    0.1500  -44.2706
    0.1750  -44.2705
    0.2000  -44.2703
    0.2250  -44.2702
    0.2500  -44.2701
    0.2750  -44.2700
    0.3000  -44.2698
    0.3250  -44.2697
    0.3500  -44.2696
    0.3750  -44.2695
    0.4000  -44.2694
    0.4250  -44.2694
    0.4500  -44.2693
    0.4750  -44.2693
    0.5000  -44.2693
    0.5250  -44.2693
    0.5500  -44.2692
    0.5750  -44.2692
    0.6000  -44.2691
    0.6250  -44.2690
    0.6500  -44.2689
    0.6750  -44.2688
    0.7000  -44.2687
    0.7250  -44.2686
    0.7500  -44.2685
    0.7750  -44.2683
    0.8000  -44.2682
    0.8250  -44.2681
    0.8500  -44.2680
    0.8750  -44.2679
    0.9000  -44.2678
    0.9250  -44.2678
    0.9500  -44.2677
    0.9750  -44.2677
    1.0000  -44.2677
    1.0354  -44.2677
    1.0707  -44.2677
    1.1061  -44.2678
    1.1414  -44.2680
    1.1768  -44.2681
    1.2121  -44.2683
    1.2475  -44.2686
    1.2828  -44.2688
    1.3182  -44.2690
    1.3536  -44.2693
    1.3889  -44.2695
    1.4243  -44.2698
    1.4596  -44.2700
    1.4950  -44.2702
    1.5303  -44.2704
    1.5657  -44.2706
    1.6010  -44.2707
    1.6364  -44.2708
    1.6718  -44.2709
    1.7071  -44.2709
    1.7504  -44.2709
    1.7937  -44.2708
    1.8370  -44.2706
    1.8803  -44.2704
    1.9236  -44.2702
    1.9669  -44.2699
    2.0102  -44.2696
    2.0535  -44.2692
    2.0968  -44.2689
    2.1401  -44.2685
    2.1834  -44.2681
    2.2267  -44.2677
    2.2700  -44.2674
    2.3133  -44.2671
    2.3566  -44.2668
    2.3999  -44.2665
    2.4432  -44.2663
    2.4865  -44.2662
    2.5298  -44.2661
    2.5731  -44.2661
    2.6085  -44.2661
    2.6438  -44.2661
    2.6792  -44.2662
    2.7146  -44.2664
    2.7499  -44.2665
    2.7853  -44.2667
    2.8206  -44.2669
    2.8560  -44.2672
    2.8913  -44.2674
    2.9267  -44.2677
    2.9620  -44.2679
    2.9974  -44.2682
    3.0328  -44.2684
    3.0681  -44.2686
    3.1035  -44.2688
    3.1388  -44.2690
    3.1742  -44.2691
    3.2095  -44.2692
    3.2449  -44.2693
    3.2802  -44.2693
    3.2802  -44.2677
    3.3052  -44.2677
    3.3302  -44.2676
    3.3552  -44.2676
    3.3802  -44.2675
    3.4052  -44.2674
    3.4302  -44.2673
    3.4552  -44.2672
    3.4802  -44.2671
    3.5052  -44.2670
    3.5302  -44.2669
    3.5552  -44.2667
    3.5802  -44.2666
    3.6052  -44.2665
    3.6302  -44.2664
    3.6552  -44.2663
    3.6802  -44.2662
    3.7052  -44.2662
    3.7302  -44.2661
    3.7552  -44.2661
    3.7802  -44.2661
 
    0.0000  -20.8317
    0.0250  -20.8322
    0.0500  -20.8338
    0.0750  -20.8364
    0.1000  -20.8400
    0.1250  -20.8445
    0.1500  -20.8497
    0.1750  -20.8555
    0.2000  -20.8618
    0.2250  -20.8684
    0.2500  -20.8751
    0.2750  -20.8819
    0.3000  -20.8884
    0.3250  -20.8947
    0.3500  -20.9004
    0.3750  -20.9055
    0.4000  -20.9098
    0.4250  -20.9133
    0.4500  -20.9159
    0.4750  -20.9174
    0.5000  -20.9179
    0.5250  -20.9179
    0.5500  -20.9178
    0.5750  -20.9175
    0.6000  -20.9172
    0.6250  -20.9169
    0.6500  -20.9164
    0.6750  -20.9159
    0.7000  -20.9154
    0.7250  -20.9149
    0.7500  -20.9143
    0.7750  -20.9137
    0.8000  -20.9132
    0.8250  -20.9126
    0.8500  -20.9122
    0.8750  -20.9117
    0.9000  -20.9113
    0.9250  -20.9110
    0.9500  -20.9108
    0.9750  -20.9107
    1.0000  -20.9106
    1.0354  -20.9102
    1.0707  -20.9089
    1.1061  -20.9068
    1.1414  -20.9039
    1.1768  -20.9003
    1.2121  -20.8959
    1.2475  -20.8910
    1.2828  -20.8855
    1.3182  -20.8797
    1.3536  -20.8736
    1.3889  -20.8673
    1.4243  -20.8611
    1.4596  -20.8551
    1.4950  -20.8495
    1.5303  -20.8444
    1.5657  -20.8400
    1.6010  -20.8365
    1.6364  -20.8338
    1.6718  -20.8322
    1.7071  -20.8317
    1.7504  -20.8322
    1.7937  -20.8338
    1.8370  -20.8365
    1.8803  -20.8400
    1.9236  -20.8443
    1.9669  -20.8492
    2.0102  -20.8545
    2.0535  -20.8601
    2.0968  -20.8659
    2.1401  -20.8716
    2.1834  -20.8772
    2.2267  -20.8826
    2.2700  -20.8876
    2.3133  -20.8922
    2.3566  -20.8962
    2.3999  -20.8997
    2.4432  -20.9025
    2.4865  -20.9045
    2.5298  -20.9058
    2.5731  -20.9062
    2.6085  -20.9063
    2.6438  -20.9064
    2.6792  -20.9067
    2.7146  -20.9071
    2.7499  -20.9076
    2.7853  -20.9082
    2.8206  -20.9089
    2.8560  -20.9096
    2.8913  -20.9105
    2.9267  -20.9114
    2.9620  -20.9123
    2.9974  -20.9132
    3.0328  -20.9142
    3.0681  -20.9151
    3.1035  -20.9159
    3.1388  -20.9166
    3.1742  -20.9171
    3.2095  -20.9176
    3.2449  -20.9178
    3.2802  -20.9179
    3.2802  -20.9106
    3.3052  -20.9106
    3.3302  -20.9105
    3.3552  -20.9104
    3.3802  -20.9102
    3.4052  -20.9100
    3.4302  -20.9097
    3.4552  -20.9094
    3.4802  -20.9091
    3.5052  -20.9088
    3.5302  -20.9084
    3.5552  -20.9081
    3.5802  -20.9078
    3.6052  -20.9074
    3.6302  -20.9071
    3.6552  -20.9069
    3.6802  -20.9066
    3.7052  -20.9065
    3.7302  -20.9063
    3.7552  -20.9063
    3.7802  -20.9062

You may notice that the first column contains the same data over and over and only the second column has different data. What I would like to do is only retain the first column from the first block and then transform into separate columns the second column. Like this:
    0.0000  -44.2709   -20.8317
    0.0250  -44.2709   -20.8322
    0.0500  -44.2709   -20.8338
    0.0750  -44.2708   -20.8364
    0.1000  -44.2708   -20.8400
    0.1250  -44.2707   -20.8445
    0.1500  -44.2706   -20.8497
    0.1750  -44.2705   -20.8555
    0.2000  -44.2703   -20.8618
    0.2250  -44.2702   -20.8684
    0.2500  -44.2701   -20.8751
    0.2750  -44.2700   -20.8819
    0.3000  -44.2698   -20.8884
    0.3250  -44.2697   -20.8947
    0.3500  -44.2696   -20.9004
    0.3750  -44.2695   -20.9055
    0.4000  -44.2694   -20.9098
    0.4250  -44.2694   -20.9133
    0.4500  -44.2693   -20.9159
    0.4750  -44.2693   -20.9174
    0.5000  -44.2693   -20.9179
    0.5250  -44.2693   -20.9179
    0.5500  -44.2692   -20.9178
    0.5750  -44.2692   -20.9175
    0.6000  -44.2691   -20.9172
    0.6250  -44.2690   -20.9169
    0.6500  -44.2689   -20.9164
    0.6750  -44.2688   -20.9159
    0.7000  -44.2687   -20.9154
    0.7250  -44.2686   -20.9149
    0.7500  -44.2685   -20.9143
    0.7750  -44.2683   -20.9137
    0.8000  -44.2682   -20.9132
    0.8250  -44.2681   -20.9126
    0.8500  -44.2680   -20.9122
    0.8750  -44.2679   -20.9117
    0.9000  -44.2678   -20.9113
    0.9250  -44.2678   -20.9110
    0.9500  -44.2677   -20.9108
    0.9750  -44.2677   -20.9107
    1.0000  -44.2677   -20.9106
    1.0354  -44.2677   -20.9102
    1.0707  -44.2677   -20.9089
    1.1061  -44.2678   -20.9068
    1.1414  -44.2680   -20.9039
    1.1768  -44.2681   -20.9003
    1.2121  -44.2683   -20.8959
    1.2475  -44.2686   -20.8910
    1.2828  -44.2688   -20.8855
    1.3182  -44.2690   -20.8797
    1.3536  -44.2693   -20.8736
    1.3889  -44.2695   -20.8673
    1.4243  -44.2698   -20.8611
    1.4596  -44.2700   -20.8551
    1.4950  -44.2702   -20.8495
    1.5303  -44.2704   -20.8444
    1.5657  -44.2706   -20.8400
    1.6010  -44.2707   -20.8365
    1.6364  -44.2708   -20.8338
    1.6718  -44.2709   -20.8322
    1.7071  -44.2709   -20.8317
    1.7504  -44.2709   -20.8322
    1.7937  -44.2708   -20.8338
    1.8370  -44.2706   -20.8365
    1.8803  -44.2704   -20.8400
    1.9236  -44.2702   -20.8443
    1.9669  -44.2699   -20.8492
    2.0102  -44.2696   -20.8545
    2.0535  -44.2692   -20.8601
    2.0968  -44.2689   -20.8659
    2.1401  -44.2685   -20.8716
    2.1834  -44.2681   -20.8772
    2.2267  -44.2677   -20.8826
    2.2700  -44.2674   -20.8876
    2.3133  -44.2671   -20.8922
    2.3566  -44.2668   -20.8962
    2.3999  -44.2665   -20.8997
    2.4432  -44.2663   -20.9025
    2.4865  -44.2662   -20.9045
    2.5298  -44.2661   -20.9058
    2.5731  -44.2661   -20.9062
    2.6085  -44.2661   -20.9063
    2.6438  -44.2661   -20.9064
    2.6792  -44.2662   -20.9067
    2.7146  -44.2664   -20.9071
    2.7499  -44.2665   -20.9076
    2.7853  -44.2667   -20.9082
    2.8206  -44.2669   -20.9089
    2.8560  -44.2672   -20.9096
    2.8913  -44.2674   -20.9105
    2.9267  -44.2677   -20.9114
    2.9620  -44.2679   -20.9123
    2.9974  -44.2682   -20.9132
    3.0328  -44.2684   -20.9142
    3.0681  -44.2686   -20.9151
    3.1035  -44.2688   -20.9159
    3.1388  -44.2690   -20.9166
    3.1742  -44.2691   -20.9171
    3.2095  -44.2692   -20.9176
    3.2449  -44.2693   -20.9178
    3.2802  -44.2693   -20.9179
    3.2802  -44.2677   -20.9106
    3.3052  -44.2677   -20.9106
    3.3302  -44.2676   -20.9105
    3.3552  -44.2676   -20.9104
    3.3802  -44.2675   -20.9102
    3.4052  -44.2674   -20.9100
    3.4302  -44.2673   -20.9097
    3.4552  -44.2672   -20.9094
    3.4802  -44.2671   -20.9091
    3.5052  -44.2670   -20.9088
    3.5302  -44.2669   -20.9084
    3.5552  -44.2667   -20.9081
    3.5802  -44.2666   -20.9078
    3.6052  -44.2665   -20.9074
    3.6302  -44.2664   -20.9071
    3.6552  -44.2663   -20.9069
    3.6802  -44.2662   -20.9066
    3.7052  -44.2662   -20.9065
    3.7302  -44.2661   -20.9063
    3.7552  -44.2661   -20.9063
    3.7802  -44.2661   -20.9062

But there is a catch! I have managed to do something close with numpy.unique but I have noticed that for some reason, Quantum Espresso will sometimes write two or more equal values in the first column blocks while the corresponding values in the second column are different and using numpy.uniques I will lose data.
I have tried this way: kp_bands=np.take(bands[:,0],range(0,122),axis=0). Here bands is where I loaded the data with numpy.loadtxt and 122 is the number of values in each block. The trouble is, this is not always the same. Could be different depending on the studied system.
My question is:
How can I do this without losing data and without knowing how many lines are in each block?

you could try going through a pandas dataframe like this question

i am really beginning to work with python and tried pandas initially but i just don't seem to understand how to work with it. numpy looks more manageable. i am really trying to build some programs to look at my data and I will have a lot of data to process.

With structured data like this pandas is really your best bet

can you give an example please?

Specific case with Numpy
Let's say we know that data are organized as a number of blocks stacked vertically, where each block consists of 2 columns, and the first column is sorted [e.g. in ascending order] and is the same for all blocks. Then we can use numpy.diff to find the number of blocks and numpy.split to separate them:
bands = np.loadtxt(file_name)
number_of_bands = 1 + np.sum(np.diff(bands[:,0]) < 0)   # or 1 + sum(bands[1:, 0] < bands[:-1, 0])
values = np.split(bands[:,1], number_of_bands)
band_len = values[0].shape[0]
index = bands[:band_len, 0]

result = np.array([index, *values]).T   # F_CONTIGUOUS
# or
result = np.c_[index, *values]          # C_CONTIGUOUS

General case with Pandas
Let's say, we want to process the data of the following pattern:
data = '''\
    0.0000  -44.2709
    0.0500  -44.2709
    0.0750  -44.2701
    0.0750  -44.2702
    0.1000  -44.2708
    0.1250  -44.2707
    0.1500  -44.2706
    0.0750  -44.2703

    0.0000  -20.8317
    0.0250  -20.8322
    0.0500  -20.8338
    0.0750  -20.8364
    0.0750  -20.8365
    0.1000  -20.8400
    0.1000  -20.8401
    0.1250  -20.8445
'''

We know that there's vertically stacked blocks separated by an empty line. And data in the first column of blocks overlap, but may not be sorted and may not match.
To work with them, I'd use Pandas. We can read them with pandas.read_csv(file, sep='\s+', ...), but I'm going to use a more specialized pandas.read_fwf method here:
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

file = StringIO(data)
first, second = 'first column', 'second column'
df = pd.read_fwf(file, names=[first, second], skip_blank_lines=False)

What is important, we keep blank lines with skip_blank_lines=False parameter in order to group data at the next step:
df['block'] = df[first].isna().cumsum()   # assign a unique number to each block
df = df.dropna()                          # drop empty lines

Now, the idea is to use one of the techniques of pivoting using the first column as index and the block's numbers as column names. But we can't do this unless the (index, column) pairs are all unique. In your case, the data in the first column can be duplicated within a block. So we need to fix this first. For example, by numbering duplicated values in a block:
df['inner_id'] = df.groupby(['block', first]).cumcount()

And now we cat pivot data, e.g:
result = df.pivot(columns='block', index=[first, 'inner_id'], values=second)

And save them as a Numpy array if necessary:
result = result.reset_index(first).to_numpy()


Code to experiment with:
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# test data, note the difference between blocks in the first column 
data = '''\
    0.0000  -44.2709
    0.0500  -44.2709
    0.0750  -44.2701
    0.0750  -44.2702
    0.1000  -44.2708
    0.1250  -44.2707
    0.1500  -44.2706
    0.0750  -44.2703

    0.0000  -20.8317
    0.0250  -20.8322
    0.0500  -20.8338
    0.0750  -20.8364
    0.0750  -20.8365
    0.1000  -20.8400
    0.1000  -20.8401
    0.1250  -20.8445
'''

file = StringIO(data)
first, second = 'A', 'B'

df = pd.read_fwf(file, names=[first, second], skip_blank_lines=False)
df['block'] = df[first].isna().cumsum()
df = df.dropna()
df['inner_id'] = df.groupby(['block', first]).cumcount()

result = df.pivot(columns='block', index=[first,'inner_id'], values=second)

Output on the test data:
>>> print(result)

block                 0        1
A     inner_id                  
0.000 0        -44.2709 -20.8317
0.025 0             NaN -20.8322
0.050 0        -44.2709 -20.8338
0.075 0        -44.2701 -20.8364
      1        -44.2702 -20.8365
      2        -44.2703      NaN
0.100 0        -44.2708 -20.8400
      1             NaN -20.8401
0.125 0        -44.2707 -20.8445
0.150 0        -44.2706      NaN

As of the data from the original post, we have duplicated records with 3.2802 in the first column in both blocks. When running the code above on those data, the result as well has 2 records with 3.2802 in index:
>>> print(result.loc[3.2802])

block           0        1
inner_id                  
0        -44.2693 -20.9179
1        -44.2677 -20.9106


thank you so much! I had found a solution myself using some assumptions about my particular data. but then you showed the numpy solution using np.diff and it eliminated those assumptions. basically knowing the number_of_bands I can just divide len(bands) by this number and I get the size of the slices I need to split the second column.

like mentioned in the comments pandas is really your best bet here
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def read_arrays(filename):
    arrays = []
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
        data = f.read().split("\n\n")
    for item in data:
        arr = np.fromstring(item,dtype=float,sep=" ")
        arr = arr.reshape(len(arr)//2,2)
        arrays.append(arr)
    return arrays

def all_to_df(numpy_arrays):
    return [
        pd.DataFrame(data=item) for item in numpy_arrays
    ]

data = read_arrays("temp.txt")
dataframes = all_to_df(data)


#some check
print(dataframes[0])
print(dataframes[1])

df = dataframes[0] #assuming at least 1 dataframe

for i in range(1,len(dataframes)):
    df = pd.merge(df,dataframes[i], on=0)

df = df.rename(columns={"0": 'timestamp',"1_x": 'value_1',"1_y": 'value_2'})

print(df)

# or use this for printing without truncating
# with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None,
#                    'display.max_columns', None,
#                    ):
# print(df)

# converting to csv is also an option
# https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html


Check df[df[0] == 3.2802] to find that doubled data were returned as Cartesian product, i.e. there's 4 instead of 2 records with 3.2802

nice find, i genuinely don't know how to solve this though

Since, @Vitalizzare already put me on the right path, I am writing here what I ended up using:
def bands_dataload(filename_glob_pattern,fermi_level):
    files=glob.glob(filename_glob_pattern)
    bands = np.loadtxt(files[0])
    number_of_bands = 1 + np.sum(np.diff(bands[:,0]) < 0)   # or 1 + sum(bands[1:, 0] < bands[:-1, 0])
#    band,no_bands=np.unique(bands[:,0],return_counts=True)
#    no_bands=no_bands[0]
#    no_kpoints=len(bands)/no_bands
    no_kpoints=len(bands)/number_of_bands
    kp_bands=np.take(bands[:,0],range(0,int(no_kpoints)))
    en_bands=np.split(bands[:,1]-fermi_level,len(bands)/no_kpoints)
    return [kp_bands,en_bands]

The commented lines were my solution. I was using the fact that these data files are quite particular in that the blocks in the first column are always the same and are mostly increasing (except for the few values that are equal sometimes). So by using the np.unique with the return_counts=True I could obtain a list of the mostly unique elements and then just choose the first one to be the no_bands which I could then use to find the length of each chunk which I can use in np.split.
The solution with np.diff removes these assumptions and straight up gives the number_of_bands value.
I learned a lot with this, mostly to RTFM! Thank you!
P.S.: I will try to wrap my head around working with pandas but when I tried, I had problems dealing with the index column and row. Numpy seemed clearer to me.
